# setTimeout not completely working

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

In the following code, the `div` animating in my `moveit()` function is waiting for the `setTimeout()` in the `.click` functions, but the `p.font-size` animation in `moveit()` is happening immediately upon the click. It's not waiting for the timeout. I'm sure it's a basic issue, but that's the level I'm at right now.

Thanks for any suggestions,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#no").click(function() {
    $("#sleep").animate({"border-width": "10px"}, "fast");
    $("#sleepanswer").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "fast");
    $("p:.sleepquestion").replaceWith("That is too bad. Tonight you will sleep better.");
    setTimeout(moveit, 2000);
  });
  $("#yes").click(function() {
    $("#sleepanswer").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "fast");
    $("p:.sleepquestion").replaceWith("That is great! A good night sleep is important.");
    setTimeout(moveit, 2000);
  });           
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function moveit() {
    $("#sleep").animate({"left": "10px", "width": "150px"}, "slow");
    $("p.sleepquestion").animate({"font-size": "16px"}, "slow");
    $("#sleepanswer").animate({ "left": "-9999px"}, "fast");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: show out your code example in http://jsfiddle.net/ please.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may have been your use of `.replaceWith()`.  That attempts to replace an element with another, but you've tried to replace an element with text.  I think you just want to use `.html()` instead.

Also, you don't need to use the `setTimeout()` - you can use `.delay()` instead.  And, I think your selectors `p:.sleepquestion` are probably not right.  You can go with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#no").click(function() {
    $("#sleep").animate({"border-width": "10px"}, "fast");
    $("#sleepanswer").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "fast");
    $("p.sleepquestion").html("That is too bad. Tonight you will sleep better.");
    moveit();
  });
  $("#yes").click(function() {
    $("#sleepanswer").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "fast");
    $("p.sleepquestion").html("That is great! A good night sleep is important.");
    moveit();
  });           
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function moveit() {
    $("#sleep").delay(2000).animate({"left": "10px", "width": "150px"}, "slow");
    $("p.sleepquestion").delay(2000).animate({"font-size": "16px"}, "slow");
    $("#sleepanswer").delay(2000).animate({ "left": "-9999px"}, "fast");
  }
</script>
```

I also changed `.replaceWith()` to `.html()` and changed `p:.sleepquestion` to `p.sleepquestion`.

Your function moveit could also be written like this by putting the timeout inside the function:

```
function moveit() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#sleep").animate({"left": "10px", "width": "150px"}, "slow");
        $("p.sleepquestion").animate({"font-size": "16px"}, "slow");
        $("#sleepanswer").animate({ "left": "-9999px"}, "fast");
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. That worked perfectly. I'm not sure why delay is better in this case than setTimeout, but it sure worked. But then I'm not sure why it was okay in the second function you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a function call in setTimeout() not working .  I solved the issue by surrounding the function call in quotes.

For example:

```
 $("#yes").click(function() {
    $("#sleepanswer").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "fast");
    $("p:.sleepquestion").replaceWith("That is great! A good night sleep is important.");
    setTimeout("moveit()", 2000);
  });
```

Comment: Yuck. You are effectively using `eval` to run the function. This is (almost) always a bad idea. Google "eval is evil" for more.